# Как удалить первые 10000 записей в mysql phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql

Нигде не нашел годного кода. Нужно удалить первые 10000 записей в таблице по id.

Comment: `delete ... where id<10000` ?

Comment: или `delete ... order by id limit 10000` ...

Comment: DELETE * FROM  `article` WHERE  `id` <10000

Так?

Comment: А `*` зачем ? http://phpclub.ru/mysql/doc/delete.html  и вы определитесь все id которые меньше 10к или первые 10к. это разные вещи, особенно если среди id есть пропуски в нумерации. в принципе я оба варианта написал

Comment: @Mike, может добавите ответом? Я бы проголосовал за имеющиеся ответы, раз уж вопрос поднят Духом сообщества, но они меня не устраивают.

Answer (score 1):

Важно понимать, что именно нужно сделать - удалить первые 10000 id или все id, которые меньше 10000.

Для первого варианта необходимо использовать код ниже:

```
delete from test
order by id
limit 10000
```

Для второго - этот:

```
delete from test
where id<10000
```

Answer (score 0):

Для удаления первых 10тыс записей, выполните запрос вида:

```
DELETE FROM table WHERE condition LIMIT 10000
```

Comment: Это удаление 10000 случайных строк.

Answer (score 0):

```
delete from [таблица] where [id] in (select [id] from [таблица]
order by [id] ASC limit 10000)

[id] - Ваше уникальное поле
[таблица] - Название таблицы
ASC - с начала (id - число)
```

мой пример:

```
delete from customers where CustomerID in (select CustomerID from Customers 
order by CustomerID ASC limit 2)
```